# Is it possible to end a python module import with something like a return?

Tags: python, python-module

I would like to know if there is a way of writing the below module code without having to add another indentation level the whole module code.

```
# module code
if not condition:
    # rest of the module code (big)
```

I am looking for something like this:

```
# module code
if condition:
    # here I need something like a `return`
# rest of the module code (big)
```

Note, I do not want to throw an Exception, the import should pass normally.

Comment: I don't know of any solution to that, but I guess you could put all your code in an internal module and import that if the condition is not met.

Comment: @UncleZeiv: that's a good idea, you should post it as an answer!

Comment: What's with the aversion to indentation?

Comment: @TokenMacGuy ok, done that, cheers.

Comment: @AustinMarshall: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8421045/880783

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of any solution to that, but I guess you could put all your code in an internal module and import that if the condition is not met.

Comment: Thanks, if nobody comes with a better idea in few days this remains the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

I know of no way to do this. The only thing I could imagine that would work would be `return` but that needs to be inside a function.

Answer (score -1):

It's super hard to say without knowing what your higher-level goal is. (For instance, what is the condition? Why does it matter? Are you DEAD SURE you're not having an X-Y problem here? Can't you just tell us what your overall goal is?) It's also really hard to say without knowing how the module is going to be called. (As a script from the command line? By being imported by another module?) And it would help a lot to know (a) why you're trying to avoid indentation (WWII is over, and we don't need to ration spaces any more; or, to put it more kindly, Python is a language that uses indentation as a SYNTACTIC FEATURE, so saying "I can't use this syntactic feature" strikes many people as a weird constraint. It's like giving up if-then tests: you might theoretically be able to work around that constraint, possibly, sometimes, but why are you going into the boxing ring with your hands tied behind your back?), and (b) why you can't throw an exception (no, really: are you TOTALLY SURE you ABSOLUTELY CANNOT THROW ANY EXCEPTIONS AT ALL?).

As it is, all you've really done is ask a "how do I do X, given conditions A, B, and C?" question, without indicating why you want to do X, or why conditions A, B, and C exist, or even whether you're 100% sure they exist and cannot be worked around.

If what you're really saying is "I don't want to hit {TAB} 40 times while writing a function," then the real problem is that you need a better text editor. If what you're really saying is "I happen to find indentation to be aesthetically unpleasant," then you should think about (a) what the other side of the argument is; that is, why people Python's use of indentation as syntax to be useful; (b) whether your own aesthetic preferences in this regard are more important than the reasons you've come up with in (a); and (c) whether, given these things, Python is the right tool for you personally to be using to accomplish whatever your own larger-scale goal is. (It's OK to not like indentation as a syntactic feature; but this is so basic to Python that being philosophically opposed to it to an extent that rules it out is a strong indication that maybe Python is not the ideal language for you to accomplish your programming goals in.) If what you're really saying is that you would benefit from factoring code that needs to be run under two different sets of circumstances into two modules, then it would benefit you to refactor. If what you're saying is that you've got spaghetti code that winds up being totally impossible to refactor, then that's really the first problem to be addressed, before you try to abort module imports.