# Skip single loop

Tags: python

I'm looping over all lines in a file, splitting each line into tokens based on whitespace. For example, a line: `circle 1 2 3` would be split into 4 tokens, `circle`, `1`, `2`, `3`.

If the line begins with a comment (`#`) or is empty, my `tokenList` is also empty. If this is the case, I can't check `tokenList[0]` etc.

If the size of the list is 0, I want to jump to the next line - the next loop in the `for` loop:

```
       for line in self.myFile:
            tokenList = self.getTokens(line)
            if len(tokenList) == 0:
                ## ISSUE HERE
            if tokenList[0] == "shape":
                s = RayTracerShapes.Shape()
                self.scene.addShape(s)
```

I tried `break`, but this seems to jump right out of the loop, rather than ending the current iteration. Is there a way to jump out of the loop I'm in, and into the next loop, without jumping right out of the for loop altogether?

Comment: Incidentally, You don't need to loop to split by whitespace. [str.split()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) can do that for you.

Comment: @acattle The `getTokens(line)` method splits on whitespace, plus does a few checking things (syntactical parsing of the tokens to ensure legal tokens), using the `str.split()` method. Thanks for the tip, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [continue](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#continue) keyword.

When `continue` is encountered the rest of the statements in the body of the loop are skipped and execution continues from the top of the loop.

This SO question might be helpful: [Example use of "continue" statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420705/example-use-of-continue-statement-in-python) and this [quick reference](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python/web/continue-statement.html) has two short examples of its use.

In your case:

```
   for line in self.myFile:
        tokenList = self.getTokens(line)
        if len(tokenList) == 0:
            continue # skip the rest of the loop, go back to top
        if tokenList[0] == "shape":
            s = RayTracerShapes.Shape()
            self.scene.addShape(s)
```