# Is the continue statement necessary in a while loop?

Tags: python

I'm confused about the use of the `continue` statement in a `while` loop.

In this [highly upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23294659/1391441), `continue` is used inside a `while` loop to indicate that the execution should continue (obviously). It's [definition](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#continue) also mentions its use in a `while` loop:

> continue may only occur syntactically nested in a for or while loop

But in [this (also highly upvoted) question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8420705/1391441) about the use of `continue`, all examples are given using a `for` loop.

It would also appear, given the tests I've run, that it is completely unnecessary. This code:

```
while True:
    data = raw_input("Enter string in all caps: ")
    if not data.isupper():
        print("Try again.")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

works just as good as this one:

```
while True:
    data = raw_input("Enter string in all caps: ")
    if not data.isupper():
        print("Try again.")
    else:
        break
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You're not missing anything - in your simple example, it's completely unnecessary. In a much more complicated example (or in more poorly organized code) it can be useful (for example, you can remove the "else" clause if you keep the continue in there).

Comment: Both examples have the same behaviour: the `continue` is programmatically useless here. In your examples, it is useful for a reviewer to understand more easily you algorithm. It can be useful too for IDEs to automatically unindent the next line like with the `pass` statement.

Comment: `continue` means: Terminate *this iteration* of the loop (i.e. *skip* the rest of the loop body) and *continue* with the next iteration.

Comment: The answers to the [question you linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420705/example-use-of-continue-statement-in-python) already explain the point of `continue`. That their examples use `for` instead of `while` doesn't matter at all. `continue` is the same for both kinds of loops.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a really simple example where `continue` actually does something measureable:

```
animals = ['dog', 'cat', 'pig', 'horse', 'cow']
while animals:
    a = animals.pop()
    if a == 'dog':
        continue
    elif a == 'horse':
        break
    print(a)
```

You'll notice that if you run this, you won't see `dog` printed.  That's because when python sees `continue`, it skips the rest of the while suite and starts over from the top.

You won't see `'horse'` or `'cow'` either because when `'horse'` is seen, we encounter the break which exits the `while` suite entirely.

With all that said, I'll just say that over 90%<sup>1</sup> of loops *won't* need a `continue` statement.

<sup><sup>1</sup>This is complete guess, I don't have any *real* data to support this claim :)</sup>

Comment: 'continue' could also be avoided by this way
animals = ['dog', 'cat', 'pig', 'horse', 'cow']
while animals:
    a = animals.pop()    
    if a == 'horse':
        break
    if a != 'dog':
        print(a)

Answer (score 2):

`continue` just means skip to the next iteration of the loop. The behavior here is the same because nothing further happens after the `continue` statement anyways.

The docs you quoted are just saying that you can *only* use `continue` inside of a loop structure - outside, it's meaningless.

Comment: Ahh so `continue` breaks *inside* the loop, while `break` breaks *outside* of it. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yeah, that's a way of looking at it. I frequently use `continue` as a way of saying 'discard the rest of this loop body, we aren't interested in it anymore. But don't exit the loop, just discard this one step in iteration.'

Answer (score 2):

`continue` is only necessary if you want to jump to the next iteration of a loop without doing the rest of the loop. It has no effect if it's the last statement to be run.

`break` exits the loop altogether.

An example:

```
items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print('before loop')
for item in items:
    if item == 5:
        break
    if item < 3:
        continue
    print(item)

print('after loop')
```

result:

```
before loop
3
4
after loop
```