# How to skip to the next for in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an crawler in python for get brands of vehicles.

My function return an array with all brands and search for models each brand.

But some brands do not have models and I would like that when the brands did not have models it would skip to the next brand and not finish running the script.

I try this:

```
all_brands = [u'Acura', u'Alfa Romeo', u'Asia', u'Aston Martin', u'Audi', u'Bentley', u'BMW', u'Buggy BRM', u'Buick', u'Cadillac', u'Carver Concept', u'Chamonix', u'Changan (Chana)', u'Chery', u'Chevrolet', u'Chrysler', u'Citroen', u'CN Auto', u'Crosslander', u'Daewoo', u'Daihatsu', u'Dodge', u'DS', u'Effa', u'Engesa', u'Envemo', u'Fargo', u'Ferrari', u'Fiat', u'Ford', u'Fyber Buggy', u'Geely', u'GMC', u'Great Wall', u'Gurgel', u'Hafei Towner', u'Haima', u'Honda', u'Hummer', u'Hyundai', u'Infiniti', u'Isuzu', u'Iveco', u'JAC', u'Jaguar', u'Jeep', u'JIN BEI', u'Jonway', u'JPX', u'Kia', u'Lada', u'Lamborghini', u'Land Rover', u'Landwind', u'Lexus', u'Lifan', u'Lincoln', u'Lobini', u'Lotus', u'Mahindra', u'Maserati', u'Matra', u'Mazda', u'McLaren', u'Mercedes Benz', u'MG', u'MG Spayc', u'MINI', u'Mitsubishi', u'Nissan', u'Oldsmobile', u'Pagani', u'Peugeot', u'Plymouth', u'Pontiac', u'Porsche', u'Rely', u'Renault', u'Rolls-Royce', u'Saab', u'Saturn', u'Seat', u'Shineray', u'Shuanghuan', u'Smart', u'Spyker', u'SsangYong', u'Subaru', u'Sunbeam', u'Suzuki', u'TAC', u'Tesla', u'Toyota', u'Troller', u'Volkswagen', u'Volvo']

for brand in all_brands:
    soup_brand = get_html(link_base + str(brand_url))

    if soup_brand is None:
        return

    print "Crawleando: "+str(count_url)+"/"+str(count_brands)
    print "Marca atual: "+brand_url

    first_vehicle = soup_brand.find(attrs={"class":"titulo_anuncio"})

    if first_vehicle is None:
        return #Here it was to jump to next tag but it to the script
```

Comment: [continue](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420705/example-use-of-continue-statement-in-python

Comment: The crawling and brands, print statements, etc, are nothing to do with the problem. See how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for `continue`

```
if soup_brand is None:
        continue
```

`continue` skips to the next iteration in a loop.