# Python exercise - don't understand how this is working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got stuck on this question on the Cisco training. I got to the answer, but don't understand why it works. Why does python remove the vowels after each 'continue'?

```
user_word = input("Enter your word: ")
user_word = user_word.upper()

for i in user_word:
    if i == "A":
        continue
    elif i == "E":
        continue
    elif i == "I":
        continue
    elif i == "O":
        continue
    elif i == "U":
        continue
    else:
        print(i)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Example use of "continue" statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420705/example-use-of-continue-statement-in-python)

Comment: `contunue` means skip the loop. So any vowel `a, e, i, o, u` gets skipped and any consonant is printed.

Comment: I find [PythonTutor](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display) quite helpful in such cases. You paste your code into the field and can see how this program is executed step by step.

Comment: FYI you can combine your if statements:
`if i in ('A','E','I','O','U'):
   continue`

Answer (score 0):

It does not "remove" them, it just does not `print()` them.

The loop is executed for each character in the word. If it is a vowel, the current iteration is ended (see the [continue](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#continue) statement) and the next character is considered. If it is NOT a vowel, it is printed to the output and you can "see" it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is as follows:

`contunue` means skip the loop, in fact it is this:

> The continue statement, also borrowed from C, continues with the next iteration of the loop

So any vowel `a, e, i, o, u` gets skipped and any consonant is printed.

by way of example, if you replace the `continue` keyword with your own function you would see this more clearly:

```py
user_word = input("Enter your word: ")
user_word = user_word.upper()

# a new function to replace continue
def replace_continue():
    print('vowel is found')


for i in user_word:
    if i == "A":
        replace_continue()
    elif i == "E":
        replace_continue()
    elif i == "I":
        replace_continue()
    elif i == "O":
        replace_continue()
    elif i == "U":
        replace_continue()
    else:
        print(i)
```

try this code and it should be more obvious.

Here is a link to the docs:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: right, so, of course, it goes through the whole code for each letter?

Comment: @sofib, exactly.  it literally just skips the vowels (or anything that triggers the `continue` keyword).

Answer (score 0):

The vowels do not get removed as in deleted, they just get ignored. **continue** is a key word, which tells the loop to go to the next iteration. If you were to put another print in the loop, outside of the if/elif statements, it becomes more visible. You may want to check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) for further information

```
for i in user_word:
    if i == "A":
        continue
    elif i == "E":
        continue
    elif i == "I":
        continue
    elif i == "O":
        continue
    elif i == "U":
        continue
    else:
        print(i)
    print('loop end')
```

Using the wourd 'continous' as value the above code yields :

```
C
loop end
N
loop end
T
loop end
N
loop end
S
loop end
```